# Issue with SharePoint 2013 Upgrade

Tags: 2013, migration, upgrade

I am facing issue with SharePoint 2013 site upgrade. 
Scenario is follows:

> 1. I took backup of database from 2010 environment
> 2. Attached it to 2013 web application
> 3. Now the site was accessible in 2013 environment with 2010 look and feel
> 4. Exported this 2013 site and imported it on different site collection on 2013 environment which was already upgraded to 2013 look
>      and feel.
> 5. After import, site is in 2010 look and feel and it is not allowing me to upgrade it to 2013 look and feel(visual upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you need to install the next CU of your version. This is a bug of a specific version of sharepoint 2013 SP1.

check this [article](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) with all build versions.